# How to make the usb accessory api compatible with android 2.3.5 and android 4.2?

Tags: android, usb

I am developing a project in `android` 4.2 environment. In this, I am using android usb accessory api.But I want to make my project compatible with `android` 2.3.5. For this, I am checking the api versions.If it is higher or equal to api level 12 means, I need to use  `"android.hardware.usb.UsbAccessory"`. or else, I use `"com.android.future.usb.UsbAccessory"`.But my program restricted to use one of the import statements.Please help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: how to code depending on the version of the API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276352/android-how-to-code-depending-on-the-version-of-the-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't conditionally import in Java, either.

The easiest way around this is to have two different classes, one which uses `android.hardware.usb.UsbAccessory` and the other which uses `com.android.future.usb.UsbAccessory`. Your factory method can check the Android version and instantiate the appropriate one.

The other way is to specify the full class name, i.e. `android.hardware.usb.UsbAccessory` instead of `UsbAccessory`. I don't recommend this; it seems simpler to use different classes.